# Accessing file downloads from containerized RSpec/Capybara and Selenium Chrome

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose, capybara

I would like to run an RSpec/Capybara test suite in Docker.  This test suite performs a file download.

If I run the test suite with rspec, I am able to access the downloaded file.

If I run both rspec and selenium chrome as containers, I cannot figure out how to access the downloaded file.

### .ruby-version

```
2.7.0
```

### Gemfile

```rb
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem 'rspec'
gem 'capybara'
gem 'capybara-webmock'
gem 'colorize'
gem 'webdrivers'
#gem 'chromedriver-helper'
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
gem 'byebug'
```

### spec/spec_helper.rb

```rb
require 'colorize'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'byebug'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.color = true
  config.tty = true
  config.formatter = :documentation
  config.include Capybara::DSL
end

def create_web_session
  Capybara.app_host = 'https://github.com'
  Capybara.run_server = false # don't start Rack

  if ENV['CHROME_URL']
    Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome_headless do |app|
      args = [
        '--no-default-browser-check',
        '--start-maximized',
        '--headless',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        '--whitelisted-ips'
      ]
      caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => {"args" => args})

      Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
        app,
        browser: :remote,
        desired_capabilities: caps,
        url: "http://chrome:4444/wd/hub"
      )
    end
  end
  @session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium_chrome_headless)
  #@session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium_chrome)
end
```

### spec/test/demo_spec.rb

```rb
require 'spec_helper.rb'
require 'webdrivers/chromedriver'

sleep 1

RSpec.describe 'basic_tests', type: :feature do
  before(:each) do
    @session = create_web_session
  end

  it 'Load page' do
    @session.visit '/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.27.0'
    @session.find_link('Source code (zip)')
    @session.click_link('Source code (zip)')
    sleep 3
    f = File.join('compose-1.27.0.zip')
    expect(File.exists?(f)).to be true
    File.delete(f)
  end

end
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.7

RUN gem install bundler

COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock

RUN bundle install

COPY . .

RUN chmod 777 .

CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rspec", "spec"]
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
networks:
  mynet:
services:
  rspec-chrome:
    container_name: rspec-chrome
    image: rspec-chrome
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      CHROME_URL: http://chrome:4444/wd/hub
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    networks:
      mynet:
    depends_on:
    - chrome
  chrome:
    container_name: chrome
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
    networks:
      mynet:
    volumes:
    - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
```

### Output when running rspec

```
basic_tests
  Load page

Finished in 8.45 seconds (files took 6.79 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

### Output when running `docker-compose up -d --build`

`docker logs -f rspec-chrome`

```
basic_tests
  Load page (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) basic_tests Load page
     Failure/Error: expect(File.exists?(f)).to be true
     
       expected true
            got false
     # /spec/test/demo_spec.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following modifications resolved my issue.

### spec/spec_helper.rb

Pass the following prefs in chromeOptions

```
        "prefs" => {
          'download.default_directory' => '/tmp',
          'download.directory_upgrade' => true,
          'download.prompt_for_download' => false
        }
```

Here is the complete file

```
require 'colorize'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'byebug'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.color = true
  config.tty = true
  config.formatter = :documentation
  config.include Capybara::DSL
end

def create_web_session
  Capybara.app_host = 'https://github.com'
  Capybara.run_server = false # don't start Rack

  if ENV['CHROME_URL']
    Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome_headless do |app|
      args = [
        '--no-default-browser-check',
        '--start-maximized',
        '--headless',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        '--whitelisted-ips'
      ]
      caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => {
        "args" => args,
        "prefs" => {
          'download.default_directory' => '/tmp',
          'download.directory_upgrade' => true,
          'download.prompt_for_download' => false
        }
      })

      Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
        app,
        browser: :remote,
        desired_capabilities: caps,
        url: ENV['CHROME_URL']
      )
    end
  end
  @session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium_chrome_headless)
  #@session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium_chrome)
end
```

### spec/test/demo_spec.rb

Change directory to /tmp and look for the download in /tmp

```
require 'spec_helper.rb'
require 'webdrivers/chromedriver'

sleep 1

RSpec.describe 'basic_tests', type: :feature do
  before(:each) do
    @session = create_web_session
    Dir.chdir "/tmp"
  end

  it 'Load page' do
    @session.visit '/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.27.0'
    @session.find_link('Source code (zip)')
    @session.click_link('Source code (zip)')
    sleep 3
    f = File.join('/tmp','compose-1.27.0.zip')
    expect(File.exists?(f)).to be true
    File.delete(f)
  end

end
```

### docker-compose.yml

Share /tmp as a docker volume between the rspec and chrome containers

```
version: '3.7'
networks:
  mynet:
volumes:
  downloads:
services:
  rspec-chrome:
    container_name: rspec-chrome
    image: rspec-chrome
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      CHROME_URL: http://chrome:4444/wd/hub
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    networks:
      mynet:
    depends_on:
    - chrome
    volumes:
    - downloads:/tmp
  chrome:
    container_name: chrome
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
    networks:
      mynet:
    volumes:
    - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    - downloads:/tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have Chrome download files they would be downloaded to the Chrome container, so to access them from the container running the tests you probably want to create a shared volume between the two containers and mount it as Chromes download directory.

Comment: I attempted to bind a volume to /home/seluser/Downloads, but I am unable to ever see my downloads appear in that folder.

Comment: @terrywb I don't know what the download directory is set to in your chrome config.  Connect to the running container after downloading the file and check where it's saving it to

Comment: Unfortunately, `docker exec -it chrome find / -name 'compose-1.27.0.zip'` does not find any files.

Comment: @terrywb Then it sounds like it's not actually downloading the file --- take a screenshot after clicking the download link and sleeping so you can see what the page thinks its done.  Are you passing the same options to Chrome when registering the driver for the runs that work? Generally there are configuration options that need to be passed to configure Chrome to not prompt for downloads.

Comment: thanks for the hints.  After modifying the preferences passed to Chrome, I was able to see the downloaded content.